# Automatic import of multiple CSV files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I have 2 folders with 365 CSV files each. However, I only need certain columns from these CSV files.
I have already solved this problem with pandas usecols. But only for one file. I want to automate the whole thing.
With an incrementing variable date

```
f{date}_sds011_sensor_3659.csv
```

I don't know what's smartest though.
loop through it first and insert it into the database at the end? insert after each loop iteration?

I've been stuck with the problem for 2 weeks, I've tried all possible variants, but I can't find a solution that covers all areas (automated import + only selected columns + skip the first line in each case)

folder names: dht22 and sds011 (the names of 2 sensors)
format of the csv file names: 2020-09-25_sds011_sensor_3659.csv
Start date: 25.09.2020
End date: 24.09.2021
400-700 rows in each file

the sds011 sensor has 12 columns and i need 3 (timestamp, P1, P2 (size of particulate matter)
the dht22 has 8 and i need 3 (timestamp, temperature and humidity)

Comment: Can you give some examples of the files in the folder? The format of their names etc.

Comment: asking what's smartest or best is meaningless here. There is so little data, that anything that works will be ok - whether you create temporary files with less columns and skipped lines first or you add it to db as you go through files

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_files = glob.glob('folder_name/*.csv', recursive=True)

all_data = []

for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, usecols=['col1', 'col2'])
    all_data.append(df)

result = pd.concat(all_data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```